# Client Initiated Logout without browser navigation

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, identityserver3

Identity Server 4 client as ASP.NET MVC 5 application and
that needs to sign out from server (without UI navigations).

Basically,

```
public ActionResult ChangeSettings(string code)
{
. . .
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,  OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);  ///How to get rid of this to redirect to Identity Server 4 as silently (no browser navigation).
}
...

}
```

I am not sure, any way for client initiated backchannel flow or some manual signout way.

Comment: Do you need to sign out from IdentityServer after signing out from your MVC application?

Comment: yes but, no UI navigation as its a in-between call.

Comment: You are signed in using cookies. so you have to do navigation to remove those cookies.